# multi line sql query

Tags: sql

table t1

```
id, name
1   shiva
2   deva
3   raju
```

i want result

```
id
name
1
shiva
2
deva
3
raju
```

can any one help me

Comment: Please tag the database you are using

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select id from table
union all
select name from table;
```

If your id is a numeric column, please convert it to string

```
to_char(id)
```

Comment: That doesn't return the values "interleaved"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to interleave values:

```
select col
from ((select cast(id as varchar(255)) as col, 1 as which
       from t
      ) union all
      (select name as col, 2 as which
       from t
      ) 
     ) t
order by row_number() over (partition by which order by col);
```

This doesn't include the headers.  Those could be brought in with additional `union all`, but I don't understand why they would appear in the data.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but the following is standard ANSI SQL:

One option is to use a lateral cross join:

```
select x.val
from data
  cross join lateral (values (cast(id as varchar(100)), id), (name, id)) as x(val, nr)
order by x.nr, x.val
```

The `order by` is necessary to guarantee that the values from the same "source row" stay together.

If your DBMS doesn't support lateral joins or the values clause, you can use a UNION

```
select val
from (
  select id, cast(id as varchar(100)) as val from data
  union all
  select id, name from data
) t
order by id, val
```